# How to add Django models into the database from the results of a Beautiful Soup website scrape?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I have written some Beautiful Soup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) code to scrape a book store website for all their books with title, author, and isbn included. Currently I am just printing the output to the screen to make sure I am scraping correctly. However, my ultimate goal is to take the information I scrape and make individual textbooks to put in my Django database.

Can someone give me an idea how to start this or point me to a tutorial which can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your data, you'll just run a for loop and create and save your Book instances:

```
# you'll need to create your instances and then save them
for book in data:
    book = Book(title=book.title, author=book.author, isbn=book.isbn)
    book.save()
```

Without seeing your data I can't really give any concrete details, but you're most likely going to have to build the `data` object above. I would create an array and then build dictionary objects to insert into the array

```
data = []

for object in scrape:
    object = {
        'title': scrape.title,
        'author': scrape.author,
        'isbn': scrape.isbn,
    }
    data.append(object)
```

Could be something like this, but it really depends on the data of what you're scraping. Hope that helps!

Comment: That's very helpful. So my next step should be to make an array of dictionaries for each book. Then I can just assign each variable in my model to one of the values in the dictionary objects for each object in my array?

Comment: I implemented the solution you gave me, worked awesome! Thanks!